# function delimiter input js

Tags: javascript, php

I have a JS function of an input text area in my source code, I'm having a little problem, below I put an example of how I wanted to leave the input, every 60 characters it gives a `\n`, I'm trying to change that and leave a `*\n` but it doesn't work, it only works with `\n`, could you tell me why?

L need this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrtbL.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xppf.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXgPY.png)

Comment: It should work the same with `.join("*\n")`

Comment: I've tried it, it doesn't work like that :(

Comment: One problem is that the `*` characters that you add will be treated as part of the value the next time you type something. So it will keep multiplying them.

Comment: How could I make it reset? Forever when they reach 60 characters they display * and \n?

Comment: Ex:
HHHHHHHHH*\nHHHHHHHHH*\nHHHHHHHHH*\n...

Comment: Strange that if you leave only the \n it does not multiply, it displays the values ​​every 10 characters, but when you put something else, for example *\n it is no longer able to display it anymore

Comment: How do you expect it to tell the difference between the `*` that it adds and `*` that are typed by the user? Like if they type `******`

Comment: The reason it works with just `\n` is that `.` doesn't match that character. Ahah! that's the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `.{1,10}` will match the `*` characters that are added, so it keeps multiplying them. `.` matches anything except newline.

So the solution is to replace `.` with `[^*\n]` so it matches anything except `*` and newline, so it won't multiply the `*` characters.

However, this also means that if the user types `*` characters in the text, they won't be part of the match that's counted.

To make this work properly as you keep editing the input, you have to remove all the `*\n` and reformat it.

```js
const conteudo = document.getElementById("conteudo");

conteudo.addEventListener("input", function(event) {
  let text = this.value.replaceAll('*\n', '');
  this.value = text.match(/[^\n*]{1,10}/g)?.join("*\n");
});
```

```html
<textarea name="conteudo" id="conteudo" rows="6" cols="50"></textarea>
```

Comment: PERFECTTTTTT very nice

Comment: I noticed that the code has some bugs, when you click on a single letter it generates correctly, after generating about 5 lines, try to modify the first or second line for example, it kind of gives a bug, could you tell me if there is how to treat it? Because if I already have this string ready like in this example: HHHHH*HHHH*HHHH*... And I want to change the first line, for example, it will give a bug, do this test for you to understand better

Comment: Good morning !!!

Comment: `*` is used for making italics in comments, so it's hard to see what you're trying to enter. Put it inside backticks to mark it as code to prevent this.

Comment: If you have a line that has already been split, and you add another character to it, it will be split again. What's supposed to happen instead?

Comment: I edited and put 3 examples of images in my question, I think you will be able to understand better. Thank you very much in advance for your help, for your time also to help me :)

Comment: The only way I can think of doing that is after every input you remove all the `*\n` and then recreate it.

Comment: Exactly that friend, when I try to change the first line by inserting a letter it inserts normally and then it stops at the last line of the text that you typed, how would I make it stop at the letter that you inserted in the middle of the line?

Comment: I've updated the answer to do that.